# Как получить список всех маршрутов и методов в Express?

Tags: node.js, express

Суть такова, нужно получить все маршруты приложения и методы этих маршрутов.
К примеру:
Файл ./app.js

```
// Подключаем Express
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// Подключаем файл с маршрутами
require('./routes') (app);
```

В файле ./routes/index.js

```
// Файлы маршрутов
var login = require('./login.js')
var users = require('./users.js')
module.exports = function(app) {
app.use('/users,users);
}
```

Файл ./routes/users.js

```
 var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
// .... Страница со списком пользователей
})
router.get('/add', (req, res) => {
// ....  Добавление пользователей
})
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
// ....  Добавление пользователей
})
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints

Comment: Спасибо @Yaant, все сработало...))) Думал уже самому какой то парсер написать или что то в этом роде)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть кому-то то пригодится.
Используя модуль [npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-list-endpoints)

Выводит мои маршруты

```
[ { path: '/login', methods: [ 'GET' ] },
{ path: '/login', methods: [ 'POST' ] },
...]
```

Для правильного вывода маршрутов лучше использовать `app.route` или `router.route`